# JRE search sequence in install4j installer in Windows

Tags: install4j

I have a Windows installer genereated with install4j 10.0.4. This installer contains a statically bundled JRE (AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-17+35). The docs ([here](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/installers/jre.html)) seem to indicate that the bundled JRE should always be used if present. However, this seems to be ignored if I set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. The 'Search sequence without bundled JRE' setting of my project is the default: 1) Windows registry and standard locations, 2) `JAVA_HOME`, 3) `JDK_HOME`.

As I said, if I point the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to a JRE 11, the Windows launcher uses it and crashes due to an UnsupportedClassVersionError, even though a bundled JRE is present. If I unset the variable everything works.

Is this a bug with install4j, or am I missing something?

This question comes from an issue in the tracker of my project: https://codeberg.org/gaiasky/gaiasky/issues/737

Comment: That should not happen. Please execute the installer from the command line with the flag /create-i4j-log and send the log file to support@ej-technologies.com.

Comment: Maybe I should have made more clear that this behavior happens when I run the actual installed application. Does it still help if I run the installer with that flag?

Comment: No, then you should run the launcher with the same flag

Comment: Apparently I was bundling JRE 20.0.1 for that specific build and the problem seems to be that the Java exe in jre/bin/ is not found ("checkJavaExe returning 0"). I rebuilt it with JRE 17 and it does work. I can confirm that the java.exe is there with the JRE 20 version.

Comment: I have sent the log files (with JRE 17 and 20) to the abovementioned address.